# Vnext Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a **generic serializer withing a Vnext project** and when I call the constructor for StreamWriter it throws this compiler error

> Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.IO.Stream'    Test.ASP.NET Core 5.0   Helper.cs   14

even though there is a constructor that allows to specify a path to a file as an argument.

this is my class file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static void SerializeToXml<T>(string path, T value)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var stream = new StreamWriter(path)) // ERROR OCCURS HERE
            {
                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my project.json file

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "run"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {

            },
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0"

            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22422",
                "System.Xml.ReaderWriter": "4.0.10-beta-22231",
                "System.IO": "4.0.10-beta-22231"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with NON-Beta code?

Comment: The `new StreamWriter(path, encoding)` overload [is supported by the portable class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) while the version with just the path is not.  Can you use that one?

Comment: @SteveWellens If I run the same code with a normal (non vnext) console project it will work. I am not sure if it is this what you meant.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @dbc I have tried using new StreamWriter(path, encoding) but I am still getting the same error, really really strange. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the Answer from [davidfowl](https://github.com/davidfowl)

> Thats because it's not available on CoreCLR. Use new
>   StringWriter(File.OpenWrite(path)) instead

For future reference where can I check if a function is available or not?

> File issues on the https://github.com/dotnet/corefx repository. They
>   will be able to clarify why things are missing in the new framework. I
>   believe the reason this particular overload was removed was because of
>   layering issues between the new packages.
>
> The assembly that contains StreamWriter shouldn't be directly
>   referencing FileStream:

```
new StreamReader(path)
```

actually does

```
new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, options)).
```